# What does "à s'en croire cocu" mean?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, registre-familier

I know that *à en croire quelqu'un* means *according to somebody*.

Then *à s'en croire* should mean *according to him / her*.

But I don't know what [*à s'en croire cocu*](http://www.cktravel.fr/articles_lecture.php?titre=Yuanyang%20terraced%20rice%20fields) actually means. It feels like an idiom beloging to informal French. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Il existe une expression française *« Avoir une chance de cocu »* qui signifie avoir une chance extraordinaire.

Dans le texte cité, les voyageurs ont effectivement la chance de n'avoir pas eu à payer le taxi lors ce périple. Ils peuvent dire *« Nous avons eu une chance de cocu »* ou son équivalent *« Nous avons eu une chance à s'en croire cocu. »*

Comment: "On a eu froid a s'en croire gelé jusqu'aux os" , je pense qu'il y a moyen de mieux expliciter "a s'en croire".

Comment: @Tensibai: Je ne vois pas cette expression dans le texte de référence. Quel est le rapport ?

Comment: Celui d'expliciter 'a s'en croire' même en dehors de l'expression 'a s'en croire cocu' puisque l'auteur de la question a visiblement un souci à l'interpréter. Je pense que cela apporterait un complément.

Comment: @Tensibai: Je pense que l'OP comprend le sens puisqu'il en indique une traduction.

Comment: Une traduction qui n'est pas correcte, "a s'en croire" serait plutôt traduit par "to feel like" que "according to him/her".

Comment: @Tensibai Tout à fait ; peut-être que l'OP a interpreté « s'en croire X » comme « se croire X (en raison) de ce qu'a dit Y ». Je suis d'accord qu'il clarifierait les choses d'ajouter une explication de la syntaxe impliquée.

Comment: @LukeSawczak *À en croire ce qu'il dit* is a perfectly good translation of "According to what he says".  "Then à *s'en croire* should mean " which implies the OP feel they're missing  something and I understand the question as asking for the difference between *à s'en croire* & *à en croire* which the present answer answers partially only since it only explains *à s'en croire* and not the difference between the 2. But still I upvoted it, hoping it will be updated.

Comment: @Laure !! Tu as raison... Somehow I relegated the correct interpretation to a secondary one, forgetting that the main reading I had in mind is simply *se croire*. Tortuous logic on my part... Still, I think the *se croire* part does mean needing to add "consider oneself" to *en*'s "according to someone".

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes *consider* would definitely be my choice of words for the reflexive use of *s'en croire.* (Consider myself lucky - How lucky),  which I think Toto explained well (hence my upvote).

Answer (score 2):

I'd translate "à s'en croire" by "to feel like" more or less literally, it is used to express something is not true (or so we hope) but we feel like it could be true anyway.

In this particular case, "cocu" refer to someone whose partner is cheating on, in France there's an usage to say someone being lucky has to be cheated on.

"à s'en croire cocu" is idiomatic in familiar tone to express that the person saying it has had a lot of luck at an unbelievable level.

In the context of the linked article, the travelers had a lot of luck to get a nice panorama view without having to pay the usual fees in the area.

Comment: I do not agree with translating by "feel like" here. But this is not relevant on FL,  ELU is made for discussing about English.

Comment: @Laure "A s'en croire cocu" -> "at a point to feel like cheated on" doesn't carry the French meaning in your mind ? (This is not aimed at being an idiomatic translation but an illustrating one of the French meaning, as such it sounds perfectly suited to this site)